# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type

Tags: android, android-intent, android-networking, android-internet

I have this function which network connection

```
public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   if (netInfo == null) {
       // There are no active networks.
       return false;
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

But when i a trying to make it static so that i can use it in every activity it is throwing:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   getSystemService(String) from the type

I don't want to create the object of the class every time .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add the non-static dependencies as parameters:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context c) {
      ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo netInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      return ( netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected() );
}
```

Comment: what is non static dependecies (what should be passed as argument)

Answer (score 4):

`getSystemService` is a non static method of the `Context` class, so in order to access it you need an object from the class Context.Typically you call it from inside an Activty where `this` is also an object of `Context` . In order to fix you could pass a Context  to your method `isNetworkConnected`

Comment: @marthajames which part exactly of "pass a Context to your method" isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

now  we  can  use static function `getContext()` to get the context which inherit from `Cocos2dxActivity.java`

Comment: Please provide an example of using it